# Calling two user defined functions in jquery

Tags: jquery, function, callback, call

Hi
I am trying to call two user defined functions and expecting the first one has to execute first and then the second one.. but they are executing simultaneously.

```
$.firstfunc = function(){
//Do something
//jQuery.ajax({
});

$.secondfunc = function(){
//Do something
jQuery.ajax({
});

$.(document).ready(function(){
$.firstfunc();
$.secondfunc();
});
```

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: And what order would you like? If you want the secondfunc to only execute once response is made from the first ajax, call `secondfunc` in the success function of firstfunc ajax.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Warning:** Requires jQuery 1.5+

```
$.firstfunc = function() {
  return $.ajax({});
}

$.secondfunc = function() {
  return $.ajax({});
}

$(function() {
  $.when($.firstfunc).then($.secondfunc);
});
```

Using the black magic of [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)'s and [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

It basically says when you first function finishes its ajax call then call the second function.

This is because [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) returns a [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object which inherits from `$.Deferred`.

If you want to attach a callback when both `$.firstfunc` and `$.secondfunc` complete then you can do the following **(requires jQuery 1.6):**

```
$(function() {
  $.first().pipe($.second).done(function(second_data) {
    // both finished.
  });
});
```

**Legacy:** jQuery 1.4.2 & 1.3.2 support.

```
$.firstfunc = function(cb) {
  $.ajax({
    success: function() {
      ...
      cb();
    },
    ...
  });
}

$.secondfunc = ...

$(function() {
  $.firstfunc($.secondfunc);
});
```

Comment: +1 good answer, you should link the docs for him as well though.

Comment: Ah yes, deferred functions. I still don't know how to use them! +1

Comment: @patrick_dw the syntactic sugar is great :) Also `.pipe` is awesome for middleware.

Comment: I am using jQuery 1.4.2 and the answer worked out for me. Thanks Raynos

Comment: @Raynos I understand and love deferred objects, though I really don't see why you added `.pipe` as a suggestion here -- I thought it's primary use is to filter before resolving the deferred objects, so surely `.when` is sufficient enough here? "If you need to use the result from $.firstfunc in $.secondfunc" -- this is exactly what your `.when` example does, it passes data from the firstfunc through the `.then` and therefore onto the secondfunc.

Comment: @GaryGreen `.pipe` returns the second deferred object where as `.then` returns the first deferred object. The main use is a shortened API for attaching a `.done` handler to the second function. Thanks for pointing out my text, I updated the answer with the relevant information

Comment: @Raynos No problem mate. It makes sense now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have the first function call the second function after the code.

```
function firstfunc() {
    // Do something

    secondfunc();
}

function secondfunc() {
    // Do something else
}
```

EDIT (now that I see your edit):

Use the callback portion of the ajax functions.

```
$.get("somepage.php", "key1=value1&key2=value2", function(data) {
    // This code will run when the result is received
});
```

Comment: @Chad: At the time of my initial post, OP had not mentioned ajax. I already edited.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because Ajax requests are processed Asynchronously.  If you want the second function to run after the first, add it to the callback function of the first Ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the second one from the callback of the first `.ajax` call.

You can either define it explicitly:

```
$.firstfunc = function(){
    //Do something
    jQuery.ajax({
        callback:$.secondfunc
    });
};

$.secondfunc = function(){
    //Do something
    jQuery.ajax({
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.firstfunc();
});
```

...or pass it as an argument:

```
$.firstfunc = function( func ){
    //Do something
    jQuery.ajax({
        callback:func
    });
};

$.secondfunc = function(){
    //Do something
    jQuery.ajax({
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.firstfunc( $.secondfunc );
});
```